# How do you say in Russian "I'm going to Ivan's" and "I'm staying at Ivan's"

Tags: грамматика

I would like to know how to say in Russian a sentence like "I'm going to Ivan's home" and "I'm staying at Ivan's home"

Comment: Is it Ivan's home or Ivan's inn or what? Please clarify what you want to express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we say that, but we don't use the possessive, just a proper noun in different cases, like a common noun.This is quite different from English.

> Я еду(иду) к Ивану, (compare:к брату).Я остановлюсь(остановился) у Ивана (у брата).